# Error when trying to use memory_profiler module

Tags: python, memory, profiling

I am trying to use the memory_profiler module to profile the memory usage of a large Python program.  There seems to be a memory leak somewhere in my program, so I'm hoping this module will help me find the leak.

I installed memory_profiler using pip and tested it with the sample code provided [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler).  This works perfectly.

When I try to use it with my program, I add the `@profile` decorator to my `main()` function and run the profiler from the command line the same way:

```
$ python -m memory_profiler engine.py
```

I get the following error, and my program fails to run (everything hangs):

```
usage: memory_profiler.py [-h] [-c CHARSET] [-i] [-o] [-l LOG_LEVEL] [-g] [-k]
                          [-w] [-s STOP] [-x TEXTS] [-z SIZE] [-t TIMEOUT]
                          [-p] [-d DEVICE]
memory_profiler.py: error: unrecognized arguments: engine.py
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Versions prior to 0.13 had a bug related to the arguments passed to the child script. Did upgrading to 0.13 help ?

Comment: After upgrading to 0.13 I no longer get the error, but there is no output printed by the profiler when the program exits.  The sample code I linked above still works fine.

Comment: I have the same error (using version 0.18). Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, I just worked around my memory problems by increasing swap space.  I'm not convinced I had a *real* memory leak, since the memory-related crashes have now stopped.

Comment: have you solved your problem? i encountered this too